# É possível limitar a velocidade da internet através do Delphi?

Tags: delphi, conexão

É possível limitar a velocidade da internet através do Delphi? Exemplo, se minha internet é de 120 KB/s eu poderei reduzi-la para 10 KB/s no meu próprio computador?

Comment: Limitar a velocidade de download dentro do aplicativo em Delphi ou do computador todo?

Answer (score 3):

A resposta óbvia é sim, se a sua aplicação tomar o controle de todos os pacotes que chegam em sua interface de rede antes de serem processados você poderá controlar e tomar ações (bloquear, limitar velocidade, redirecionar, etc).

A ideia básica de um limitador de banda é bem simples, você enfileira os pacotes que chegam em um Buffer, a largura de banda é simplesmente o tempo que cada pacote fica neste buffer antes de ser processado, isso nós diz que quanto maior o tempo de espera do pacote menor será sua taxa de transferência e claro a reciproca é verdadeira, uma analogia fácil de se visualizar é você imaginar um tanque cheio de água, tire a tampa do tanque para a água escoar, o tempo que vai demorar para a água escoar vai depender do tamanho do buraco de escoamento.

Você vai precisar conhecer a velocidade de sua placa de rede (buraco de escoamento) para poder calcular o tempo de espera de cada pacote no buffer. É claro isso é uma abordagem extremamente simplista só para que você consiga ter uma visão do básico de como qualquer limitador de banda funciona. Lembrando que este tipo de implementação limita toda a placa de rede, portanto internet e rede interna serão tratados da mesma maneira, se você quer manter sua rede interna fora do limite de banda identifique todos os pacotes da sua classe de IP interna e os mantenha fora da fila.