# Limitar Banda de um WebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Tenho no meu form um WebBrowser que transmite um video do site hitbox.tv

Eu queria limitar o quanto de banda estaria disponivel pro WebBrowser

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89132/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-limitar-a-velocidade-da-internet-atrav%C3%A9s-do-delphi

Comment: O Webbrowser usa a API do Internet Explorer. Então acredito que não seja fácil aplicar essa limitação. Poderia explicar qual seu objetivo com isso? Talvez haja uma outra forma.